# Exchange unicode characters between android app and services

Tags: android, android-volley

I using Volley library, StringRequest class to exchange data between client and server. My database records on server are saved in UTF-8 charset. Now when I want to get the records using StringRequest,They are not in a correct format!

My code:

```
    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    Log.d(TAG, response);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                }
            });
```

What I can do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should override `parseNetworkResponse` method, change `response.data` charset and return it. There is a sample on following.

```
StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Method.GET, url,

            new Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                }
            }, new ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }

            }) {

        @Override
        protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(
                NetworkResponse response) {

            String strUTF8 = null;
            try {
                strUTF8 = new String(response.data, "UTF-8");

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return Response.success(strUTF8,
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        }
};
```